# Instalar y correr python en ordenador remoto (windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, servidor, ssh, rdp

os pongo en situación: tengo mi ordenador principal (A) que es desde el que programo en Python en Spyder, y tengo un portátil (B) que solo voy a dedicar a esto. Ambos con windows 10 y por el momento en la misma intranet. La historia es que los códigos toman su tiempo en terminar, y son muchos.

He dejado (B) configurado para que esté encendido 24/7, la idea es poder conectarme a él en remoto para lanzar los scripts desarrollados en (A) y luego recuperar los archivos de salida de cada script.

¿Me podéis dar alguna recomendación? ¿Qué es lo mejor que puedo hacer? La solución de escritorio remoto y una carpeta compartida en la nube es demasiado burda. De hecho, me interesaría configurar un demonio para que corra los scripts cada cierto tiempo.

Muchas gracias,

hda

Comment: Opciones hay muchas, empezando por  SSH, Spyder puede conectarse a núcleos IPython en ejecución remota de forma simple usando SSH: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel. Si quieres que simplemente la máquina remota ejecute x script cada x tiempo, simplemente usa carpetas compartidas. Otra opción "menos burda" podría ser crear un servidor web que actúe de intermediario y permita subir los scripts y  descargar los resultados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, @FJSevilla , al final me he decantado por instalar una distro a través de WSL 1 y conectarme en remoto por SSH para lanzar los scripts y un FTP para recuperar las salidas. Más adelante crearé un demonio para hacerlo recurrente.

Comment: Puede utilizar Windows Task Scheduler para lanzar los programas.  Estoy de acuerdo del uso de carpetas compartidas.  Tambien puede hacer mucho con PowerShell. Ojo que RDP no funciona con Windows Home.  En ese caso necesito algo como VNC.